# Issue with Textview while Using AutoLink

Tags: android, textview, autolink

Whenever I am using **autoLink="all"** in **TextView**, it is not properly autolinking the Mobile Number. It is autolinking the earlier Number(number from a text not mobile Number) as well.

Here is the layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The output is attached below

[image: Issue Image]

How to avoid that issue ?

Comment: try to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788608/androidautolink-for-phone-numbers-doesnt-always-work

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question clearly than you can also use **ClickableSpan**
It also allows you to under line and clickable the fix number of characters handle the click for the same.
In xml

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_18sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_18sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_semibold"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />
```

In java class

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello World8 123456789");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        // handle on click
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);

    }
};
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 12, 22, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```